# Положения дива не изменялось с размера экрана

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Как сделать чтобы положения дива не изменялось с размера экрана .Чтоб во всех экранах показывался одинаково . Как сделать ? 100% пробовал

Comment: покажите код

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/976Ha/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А Вы стили сбрасывали до начала работы? Может помочь!
Так как разные браузеры по своему делают отступы и тп.

```
﻿/* reset browser styles */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1.2;
}
ol { 
    padding-left: 1.4em;
    list-style: decimal;
}
ul {
    padding-left: 1.4em;
    list-style: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

/* end reset browser styles */
```

Добавте этот код либо в Вашу основную табл стилей, либо отдельным CSS файлом.
00px

Comment: так тоже делал . У меня норм показывает но у каждого по разному